# define Array without allocating it

Tags: python, numpy, allocation, numba

I see that Numba does not support Dict-of-Lists ... Thus, I decided to use 2D Numpy arrays instead. This is sad :(

The second problem I have is that I want to create this array on demand. Here is an example:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def blah(cond=True):
    ary = None
    if cond : ary = np.zeros((10000,2))

    for i in range(5):
        if cond: ary[i] = np.array([i,i])

    return 555, ary
```

The problem is `ary` cannot be `None`, so I have to allocate the array even if i do not use it.

Is there a way to define `ary` without allocating it, so that Numba wont complain?

> The 'parallel' seems to cause the problem ??

---

interesting too that this updates only the first row (i is incremented):

```
ary[i,:] = np.array([a,b])
```

but this works

```
 ary[i] = np.array([a,b])
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine. Numba 0.53 works surprisingly well with `None` values (the code just do not build because `abc` and `cond` are not defined but aside from this it is fine). Did you tested the last version?

Comment: 0.48 ..but 0.53 too : Dimension mismatch

Comment: If you're having a problem down the line, this is not a [mcve]

Comment: updated the Q... parallel

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to be parallelized, then yes, it absolutely has to be allocated first. You can't have multiple threads trying to resize an array independently.

Comment: i suspected that, better parallel 10 vs 3 ms ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider allocating a zero size array instead of None. That would make the type identical regardless of the condition being True or False.

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def blah(cond=True):
    
    if cond:
        ary = np.zeros((10000,2))
    else:
        ary = np.zeros((0,0))

    for i in range(5):
        if cond:
            ary[i ,:] = (i, i)

    return ary

blah(cond=False)
```

It's also a lot faster to avoid initializing a new array in each iteration of the loop (`np.array([i, i])`), if that's possible of course.

Explicitly using Numba's `prange` for the loop might help a little, but that usually only becomes significant if you do a more intensive computation inside the loop. This example is so simple that the overhead of parallelization is not really worth it.

```
for i in nb.prange(10000):
    if cond:
        ary[i, 0] = i
        ary[i, 1] = i
```